# Gurobi API Exceptions (GRBException) with IronPython

Tags: c#, .net, ironpython, gurobi

I have a problem running a Gurobi Optimization Model using a C#/.NET library through IronPython.

I have a method to access variables though their name (ie GRBModel.GetVarByName), something like

```cs
    public GRBVar variable(i,t)
    {
        try 
        {
            GRBModel M = getModel();
            string varname = varname(i,t);
            GRBVar var = M.GetVarByName(varname);
            return var;
        }
        catch (GRBException ex)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            throw new GRBException(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

The problem is that on my IronPython script, when I try to access a non existing variable, nothing happens... the message doesnt appear on the console. What I'm doing wrong???

Comment: When you throw in the `catch` clause, you do not need to create a new `GRBException` instance; `throw;` or `throw ex;` will automatically pass on the `catch`:ed exception. If you call the `variable()` method from C#, what is written to the console then? I don't have Gurobi so I cannot test, but as I mentioned in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15818307/650012) I *do* believe that you should output `ex.Message` or `ex.ErrorCode` rather than `ex.ToString()`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing a return statement somewhere; if you catch the exception, the method does not return. (Doesn't the C# compiler error in that case?)

If this method is just for IronPython, you could just let the exception pass through to IronPython and deal with it there.

Comment: I need to print de exception on console and terminate execution. Also, the application isnt inteded to run on IronPython... I need Ironpython just for testing issues...

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/5.1/reference-manual/node516) page in the Gurobi .NET Reference Manual, `GRBException` inherits from the .NET [Exception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.aspx) class. To obtain the error message from an `Exception` based class you should use the [Message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.message.aspx) property rather than the `ToString()` method, which by default normally displays only the class name for reference classes.

In other words, change the `catch` clause to:

```
catch (GRBException ex)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

Alternatively, you could output the [ErrorCode](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/5.1/reference-manual/node518) property which is specific to the `GRBException` class.